# Ubuntu server 18.04 user permissions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, user-accounts, dropbox

I've set up an Ubuntu Server 18.04 where I have a Dropbox app running over user0. This app is set up to make a directory backup. I have two directories: `/home/user/dropbox/user1` and `/home/user/dropbox/user2`. Both folders ownerships are set to user0. I created two more users on the server, `user1` and `user2`. How can I give each user read and write permissions to these folders? This folders will be accessible from a Samba share where user1 will work with `/home/user/dropbox/user1` and user2 will work with `/home/user/dropbox/user2`. user1 should not be able to see user2 files. Thanks!